# byte array of image gets stored as String, how to get it back to byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, spring

I'm using android as my front end and Spring with Hibernate as my back-end. I send a byte array of my image to get stored in this entity:

```
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image_bytes", columnDefinition="BLOB")
    private byte[] imageBytes;
}
```

However, in the H2 console i can see it gets stored as a String, hundreds of characters, so i quess the byte array was in some way converted to a string. So my questions:

- Why is this happening ? Why does it get stored as a String? Why not store the byte array as it is ?
- If it has to get stored as a String, then how can i decode it back to the right byte array? If i take the string, and do a `myStringThatGotReturned.getBytes()`, i get a diffrent byte array ( so basicly i dont get the right image back). I quess im not decoding it in the right way. Any way i can figure out how to decode that string back to the byte array i sent to the back-end ?

Comment: It might be a storm in a glass of water (Dutch proverb). Maybe it internally is stored as (Base64?) string, but certainly bytes are received back (in some manner). Though bytes should never be stored as String, which internally works with Unicode, UTF-16, and hence costs both a conversion and double memory (char = 2 bytes)

Comment: Is there any way i can find out in what way it gets stored? Since it gets automatically converted to a String, i can't find out how the conversion happens.

Comment: Show the code where it does that.

Comment: I dont have that code, since Hibernate maps in to the database. I only have the code of the entity, which cleary has a column that is byte[]. But when i return in to the android in the JSON object it's a String of characters.

Comment: Then it is a JSON conversion problem. As JSON is a text format, binary data like those bytes often are converted to Base64 using digits, capitals, small letters and two symbols `+` `/` = 64 "digits" each representing 6 bits. Or is it gibberish.

Comment: The string i receive looks like this: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2 ......

Comment: Indeed Base64. So probably the handling by the JSON library already works. You could convert the String value yourself with `bytes[] b = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);`

Comment: Decoding it using Base64.decode worked. Thanks for the clarity @JoopEggen. You can put it as an answer and i will give you an accepted answer. Also thanks to everyone who downvoted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **JSON** conversion problem. As JSON is a text format, binary data like those bytes often are converted to Base64 using digits, capitals, small letters and two symbols `+` `/` = 64 "digits" each representing 6 bits.

So probably the handling by the JSON library already works. You could convert the String value yourself with

```
bytes[] b = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
```

Comment: As an extra question, since storing and retrieving the image like this doesn't seem right, do you know how i can store it like a normal byte[] array using Hibernate?

Comment: Hibernate, or more general JPA (Hibernate, eclipseLink) is an O/R (object relational) mapping, and will deliver type-safe the entity, or a list of entities of class `ApplicationUser` by typed JPA queries in a look-alike of SQL, hql / jpql. Other search key would be criteria builder, TypedQuery, getResultList. Search in the web for numerous examples.

Comment: @AskQuestions; re your extra question about storing the image.  You should consider using something like the community project Spring Content (https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-rest-docs/).  byte[] are problematic for other reasons.  For example, large files may induce `OutOfMemoryException`s as the entire image has to be loaded into memory as it transits through your application.  Spring Content provides an abstraction for Spring Resources in general, provides stream access to those Resources and hides all of the database & storage-specific details.

Comment: @PaulWarren that is a useful tip. And not to forget the filesystem, storing a generated file name/ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of this:

```
byte[] b = string.getBytes();
byte[] b = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] b = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```